# how to use $resource with resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, resolve

I'm trying to use angular's resolve when trying to navigate between routes:

```
when('/user',
   {
      templateUrl: 'partials/user.html',
      controller: 'UserController',
      resolve: { auth: RouteAuthenticationCheck }
})
```

This works fine when I use $http because it returns a promise:

```
var RouteAuthenticationCheck = ['$http', function ($http){
    return  $http.get('/login');
}];
```

But when I use $resolve, it does not.. and this code would not work:

```
var RouteAuthenticationCheck = ['$resource', function ($resource){
    return $resource('/login').get();
}];
```

What is the appropriate way to uses $resource to resolve when changing routes?

Comment: Did you try `return $resource('/login').get().$promise`

Comment: indeed the $http version worked because it returns a promise, you must do the same with the $resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try returning the promise from the $resource:

```
var RouteAuthenticationCheck = ['$resource', function ($resource)
{
    return $resource('/login').get().$promise;
}];
```